# fatal: adding files failed when upgrading a Unity project to a newer Version

Tags: unity-game-engine, gitlab

Hi2,

Have anyone encounter an error message in Gitlab like this?

```
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Library/PackageCache/com.unity.multiplayer-hlapi@1.0.2/Tests/Runtime/GetCurrentRTTCallDoesntCrashWhenUseWebSockets/Resources.meta.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
error: open("Library/PackageCache/com.unity.multiplayer-hlapi@1.0.2/Tests/Runtime/GetCurrentRTTCallDoesntCrashWhenUseWebSockets/Resources/GetCurrentRTTCallDoesntCrashWhenUseWebSockets_PlayerPrefab.prefab"): Filename too long
error: unable to index file Library/PackageCache/com.unity.multiplayer-hlapi@1.0.2/Tests/Runtime/GetCurrentRTTCallDoesntCrashWhenUseWebSockets/Resources/GetCurrentRTTCallDoesntCrashWhenUseWebSockets_PlayerPrefab.prefab
fatal: adding files failed
```

This error occurs after I upgrade my unity project project from 2018.3 to 2019.2

Comment: Did you try deleting the "Library" folder from Project folder?

Comment: i would prefer not to delete those library, because it is an official library from the unity for the multiplayer.

Comment: @Hikari Library is a temp folder and doesnt need to be kept.  It will remake it but will clear out old unnecessary data (you can see normal things to ignore if you google unity gitignore)

Comment: @BugFinder Thank you very much its working now. ^_^
for anyone else that have problem like mine, I use this .gitignore: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore

Comment: @BugFinder : if you have sometime, would you be so kind to give me a pointer to solve this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56578200/gitlab-have-an-error-remote-unpack-failed-eof-before-pack-header-was-fully-rea

Comment: You already said it was solved.. so I dont know what else you expected

Comment: it is a link to another question about git that i havent solve it yet until now. :)